# ssh port is different from what is connected

Tags: centos, ssh, iptables, firewall

Ok,

so here's the deal. I setup an Iptables rule as follows:

```
IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 51722 -j ACCEPT
```

and if I do `systemctl status sshd.service`, I get the following:

```
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 51722.
```

Ok. That's what I want. I then ssh as such `ssh -p 51722 root@MY.IP.ADDRESS`

once I login, I check status of sshd again and notice.

```
Accepted password for root from MY.IP.ADDRESS port 49344 ssh2
```

Why is it showing that it is on Port 49344 as opposed to 51722?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because ssh uses [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).The logged port is port that the client is using to connect, not the port the server accepted the connection on.

Your `netstat -tp` output will have a line similar too:

```
tcp    0    0 server.example.com:51722    client.example.com:49344    ESTABLISHED 15825/sshd
```

Comment: ah, ok cool. didn't know about ephemeral ports.